# How to group a variable like '3letters+4digits' in terms of '3letters+ 1st + 2nd + 4thdigit'?

Tags: regex, r

I want to rename strings like 'BLA2501' and 'BLA2561' into 'BLA251'.
In some words, I have a variable in my dataframe which takes values like

```
  'BLA2501', 
  'BLA2521'.
  'BLA3601',
  'BLA5501'.
```

I want to localize those values and group them in terms of 'BLA + 1st digit + 2nd digit + last digit'.

For example

```
  'BLA2501' and 'BLA2521' have to be renamed as 'BLA251', 
  'BLA3601' will be 'BLA361' 
   ...
```

I've tried something like

```
  data$var<-sub('^BLA(\\d)(\\d)(\\d)(\\d).*', 'BLA\\1\\2\\4', data$var)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the regex you've tried?

Comment: And od all strings have the same format/number of digits? (Does a string like BLA550001 occur?)

Comment: @SparkUser what's wrong with your regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the second number from last.

```
sub("\\d(\\d)$", "\\1", s)
```

or

```
sub("^(BLA\\d{2})\\d(\\d)", "\\1\\2", s)
```

Comment: I want first to fitler the value like 'BLA+4digits', if I try sub("BLA\\d(\\d)$", "\\1", s) it doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: or `sub("^(BLA\\d{2})\\d(\\d).*", "\\1\\2", s)` and I don't know what's wrong with your original regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
x<-"bla2501"
paste0(substr(x,1,5),substr(x,7,7))
```

That does the trick.

Comment: But my problem is that my variable has other value like 'ars_69' or 'poi-ter-6_5' , I want to filter the value like 'BLA+4digits' and then transform only the value like this.

Comment: @SparkUser I see.  Often solutions will only be robust enough for the example input.  If you would have given those example values in question then i would have known.  Looks like you've already got an answer that works with those examples but, just for next time, try to give example input that is representative of the complexity of your situation.